# Custom List with iterator, error when trying to make pointer to nested node class

Tags: c++, oop, stl

I am trying to implement a simple list with iterator for practice, however I have encountered a compile error that I don't fully understand I had not been able to fix it. When I try to make pointer in my Iterator class to a Node I get compilation error as follows:

> use of class template requires template argument list

Here is my headre file that produces the compile error:

```
#ifndef _MY_LIST_H
#define _MY_LIST_H
#include <memory>



template<class T> 
class MyListItr;

template<typename T>
class MyList {
private:
    int _size;
    friend class MyListItr<T>;
public:
    class Node {
    private:
        T value;
    public:
        std::unique_ptr<MyList::Node> next{ nullptr };

        Node() = delete;
        Node(T& value, MyList::Node* next) :value(value), next(next) {};
        T getVal()const { return value; };
        void setVal(T value) { this->value = value; };
        ~Node() {};
    };

    std::unique_ptr<MyList::Node> head;
    MyList(const MyList<T>&) = delete;
    MyList& operator=(const MyList<T>) = delete;
    MyList() :_size(0), head(nullptr) {};
    int size()const { return _size; };
    void push_front(T);
    T pop_front();
    T front()const;
    void remove(T);
    MyListItr<T> begin() {return MyListItr(this->head); };
    MyListItr<T> end();
    typedef MyListItr<T> iterator;
    typedef MyList<T>::Node value_type;
    typedef MyList<T>::Node* pointer;
    typedef MyList<T>::Node difference_type;
    typedef MyList<T>::Node& reference;

};

template<typename T>
class MyListItr {
    MyList::Node* data;

public:
    MyListItr(MyList::Node*data) : data(data) {}

    bool operator!=(MyListItr<T>const&) const;
    MyListItr<T> operator++();
    T operator*();
};


#endif
```

I would be gratefull for any help or direction as to where to look for any clues.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You class `MyListItr` needs to be

```
template<typename T>
class MyListItr {
    typename MyList<T>::Node* data;

public:
    MyListItr(typename MyList<T>::Node*data):data(data) {}
    // ...
};
```

Note that you need to use the `typename` keyword to tell the compiler that data you are using a type, and not a variable.

Comment: Thanks, it works. I was trying to use 
`MyList<T>::Node*` but did not realise that `typename` keyword was also needed.

Comment: Yeah, the compiler needs help to disambiguate. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/610245/8372853) for a great explanation.

Answer (score 0):

You must specify a template parameter in case when it cannot be automatically deduced (automatic template parameter deduction in class templates was introduced in C++17).

You have several lines, where you don't specify template parameters:

```cpp
MyListItr<T> begin() { return MyListItr(this->head); /* Here you forget semicolon */};
MyList::Node* data;
MyListItr(MyList::Node*data):data(data) {}
```

You mast rewrite them like following:

```cpp
MyListItr<T> begin() { return MyListItr<T>(this->head);};
typename MyList<T>::Node* data;
MyListItr(typename MyList<T>::Node*data):data(data) {}
```

In the first line compiler can't deduce template parameter of `MyListItr` by return type (I think, you thought, that if you have specified template parameter in return type, compiler can "remember" it), because, for instance, `MyListItr`s with different template parameter can be convertible to each other...

In other lines compiler knows nothing about `MyList`, because it is not quite clever to realize, that your list and its iterator should have the same template parameters. It is more about user-defined semantics.

You must write `typename` in second and third lines, because this type depends on template parameter. Here is some explanation: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/dependent_name

Moreover, you'd better rename the argument in the following line, because it can have conflict with template parameter name:

```cpp
bool operator!=(MyListItr<T> const& T_)const;
```

Furthermore, you can try to declare iterator inside the class of your list and it'll automatically bind types inside. In this case you can also hide `Node` from user code and declare it in private section.